# Como pasar variable al nombre de una tabla en consulta mysql con python

Tags: python, mysql

Quiero pasar una variable al nombre de una tabla en una consulta mediante mysql.connector, ¿cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO %s (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), %s, %s,%s", (lista[0], lista[1], lista[2], lista[3]))

    print(sql)
    try:

        cursor.execute(*sql)
        db.comit()
        

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Esto me devuelve el siguente error al pasar el parametro al nombre de la tabla:

> ('INSERT INTO %s (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), %s, %s,%s', ('tabla', '444', '242', '4440'))

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tabla' (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), '444',' at line 1

También he intentado:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO '"+lista[0]+"' (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), '"+lista[1]+"' , '"+lista[2]+"' ,'"+lista[3]+"' ")

    print(sql)
    try:

        cursor.execute(*sql)
        db.comit()
        

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Y esto me devuelve:

> INSERT INTO 'tabla' (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), '444' , '242' ,'4440'
>
> execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 109 were given

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error estaba en la sintaxis, de la siguiente manera funciono:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO `"+lista[0]+"` (date, var1, var2, var3) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(),interval 0 hour), '"+lista[1]+"' , '"+lista[2]+"' ,'"+lista[3]+"');")
    print(sql)
    try:

        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```